# Accessing AngularJS app Service in Karma test

Tags: testing, angularjs, automated-tests, karma-runner, angularjs-e2e

I am trying to write an e2e test in Karma for an angularJS app. I have automated filling in a form and posting it. The result should be an object, which can be accessed by calling a custom service "UserService" - well, at least in the app code. But how do I access this service inside my test code? I would like to be able to write:

```
expect(UserService.parent.firstname).toEqual('Jack');
```

I have tried including the service by the line

```
beforeEach(module('App'));
```

in the e2e test code. But all I get is "*Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined*".

The app module is defined as 'App':

```
var myApp = angular.module('App', ['App.filters', 'App.services'])....
```

The service is defined as part of the 'App' module:

```
myApp.factory('UserService', ['webStorage', function(webStorage) {...
```

I have just included the definitions here, as I already know the app and the service work. How can I use the service inside the test? I don't want to mock it, just use it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add it in a beforeEach() block with inject().

This should work:

```
var uService;

beforeEach(inject(function (UserService) {
    uService = UsersService;
}));
```

And then you use it as `uService.parent.firstname`

Also I see you have `App.services` as a dependency of your main app's module, but still you define the service as part of the main app's module and not of the App.services module. Deliberate or accidental?

Comment: Tried this, but I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: inject is not defined"..?

Comment: Per: You need to include angular-mocks.js